# Typeahead value disappears from field after selecting value - JS

Tags: javascript, typeahead

I am using typeahead search and when I search and select an item, the item selected disappears from the field. How can I make sure the value doesn't disappear from the field?

```
$.get("searchProducts", function (data) {
    $("#product-search").typeahead({
        "items": "all",
        "source": data,
        "autoSelect": false,
        displayText: function (idata) {
            return idata.quantity;
        },
        updater: function (idata) {

          ("#product-search").val(idata.name);
          ("#name").val(idata.name);



        }
    });
});

<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="product_search" id="product-search" class="form-control" required>

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: Which typeahead library are you using? Probably not the typeahead.js that you added as tag, because this does not have the attributes given in your code snippet. Please try creating an example showcasing the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. using stackblitz, plnkr or jsfiddle

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? `$("#search")` doesn't match any elements in your code snippet.

Comment: On the face of it, it looks like you're attaching the typeahead functionality to the element after a single HTTP GET returns. If your `searchProducts` page filters its results based on input from your input, it won't get it unless you run the query every time the input updates; you're only running the GET once.

Comment: @amphetamachine, but I am able append values into other fields with the products returned from the search but not the one in which i type to search

Comment: @amphetamachine please look at the update.. After selecting, the `name` field is populated but not the `product_search` field

Comment: You still have runtime errors in your code: `("#name").val(idata.name);` will cause a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same situation.

The typeahead documentation explain it better, but you should use the typeahead setter `.typeahead('val', value)` rather than the `jQuery.val()`.

```js
//wrong ("#product-search").val(idata.name);

("#product-search").typeahead('val', idata.name);
```

Follow the link for more info.
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadval-val